# Navigation drawer template in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I use the Navigation drawer template on Android Studio 1.4 (the one with `activity_main.xml`, `app_bar_main.xml`, `content_main.xml`, `nav_header_main.xml`)

I was able to change it (icons, methods,...) to feed my needs,

The problem is that I want all my activities to have the same navigation drawer, so in each Java file of my activities, I extend the activity containing the navigation drawer. It didn't work.

So tried to I include the layout of the activity which contains the navigation drawer. And it's not working too.

Can you give me some suggestions how to make it work?

Here the java and xml files:

1- mainactivity.java

```
package com.ther01s.android.wabamon;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Rubriques extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rubriques);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rubriques, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_categories) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) { profil();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void profil() { Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profil.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

2-mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ther01s.android.wabamon.Rubriques">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

           <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_rubriques"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_rubriques"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_rubriques_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

3-firstactivity.java

```
package com.ther01s.android.wabamon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class Catalogue extends Rubriques {


    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_catalogue, null, false);


        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);


    }

}
```

4-firstactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ther01s.android.wabamon.Catalogue">



    <include layout="@layout/content_catalogue" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: why dont you add fragments to your navigation drawer instead of activities. so u can access your navigation drawer from each of your navigation item.

Comment: if you post your mainactivity.java and xmls , i can suggest you better modifications.

Comment: @Rubin Nellikunnathu - i wil post the mainactivity.java and xml as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use only one Activity. All your content would be in Fragments. When the user selects an item in the navigation drawer, the Fragment displayed by the Activity is swapped out. This way you'll also have a smooth animation for the drawer, as the Activity containing the drawer is not finished.

Comment: i will give a try to your suggestion. Can you give me best link to a tutorial on using fragments on my app?